# Trouble with aligning container in BootStrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, visual-web-developer

I am new to web development and was having an issue with aligning a container on my webpage. For some reason any text on the page is updating, but when I try to align the container in the center of the page using  (line 30) the page updates but there's no change. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong, also my code is provided below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
                <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
                <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div>
            <div>             
                <div>
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                   </address>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
                        <a href="mailto:">Mail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div>             
                <div>
                    <p>© Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the bootstrap 4 flex [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)? `d-flex align-items-center`

Comment: I've tried using that, but for some reason it won't register the command. Like its updating the page if I change the text in the HTML file in VScode, but any sort of alignment is not being reflected on the webpage.

Comment: Other bootstrap library items are working in your code though? Perhaps you could reproduce your issue using the built in snippit in SO?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hard refresh your browser everytime you change or add bootstrap classes in your page or css styles. F12 and right click the refresh icon then select **Empty Cache and Hard Reload**. Make sure you Open your webpage first.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and checked the dev settings on chrome, and ended up seeing the following error.Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. Any idea how I can fix this, as I think this is the error stopping me from applying the container class.